# Is it permissible to play zombie games?

Tags: halal-haram, game

Is it permissible to play zombie games?

Since Allah is the Resurrector:

Noble Qur'an [22:7](http://tanzil.net/#22:7) :

> And verily the Hour will come: there can be no doubt about it, or about (the fact) that Allah will raise up all who are in the graves.

and zombie games are about fighting the undead. So, is it Haram(impermissible)?

I think, maybe it is. But I don't know much.

Comment: In islam there is no concept like zombies and in real life also there are no zombies It's just an another man made story.

Answer (score 1):

By paying attention to an aspect of this issue, we can look at it solely as a game. But as you yourself mentioned that Zombie games are about fighting the undead…, and perhaps could be the cause of blot of God.

So as a general Islamic rule, it could be considered as a haram practice if is related to showing a flaw to the acts of god or indicating another creature as a creature which is able to do the acts of Allah. Thus it would be better if you leave playing this kinds of games.

Answer (score -2):

Allah in Qur'an says [...surly Allah don't likes the wasters(6:141)] and I think playing of many games are wasting time.  so avoid wasting your lifetime because Allah doesn't likes the wasters.

There is Raja'at in Islam (2:259) research about it.

Comment: Your point of not wasting time is good one. But Qur'an 6:141 is not about wasting time, it's about wasting money. Please consider editing it, providing more resources, and try to answer better.

Comment: Yes, as @servantofWiser said, the Aya is not about wasting time.
However, wasting time is not allowed, as you said. In Quran, "عملوا الصالحات" (more than 100 times in different places -e.g. 2:82), means "doing righteous deeds", but it's the literal translation. In Arabic "الصالحات" also means "worthy things/deeds", so "عملوا الصالحات" means "doing worthy deeds" or in other words "doing something which is worth spending your lifetime" -Since time the most valuable gift from God.

Comment: ...It's obvious that Quran doesn't prevent us from relaxation, nor from entertainment -they are necessary, but it prevents us from wasting our lives.

Comment: So, even playing Zombie games is a form of entertainment. How is it specifically prohibited, or playing any computer games prohibited then?

Comment: In addition to my last comments, Aya 23:1 followed by 23:2 & 23:3 clearly says that believers must turn away from "لغو" which means "useless deeds".

Comment: Yes, now you're some what closer with Qur'an 23:3. But, it cannot be deduced as not playing games. Fine. Good attempt though. As you're new, I think you can try answering other questions related to Arabic, Qur'an and Hadith. All the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21954/discussion-between-servantofwiser-and-moctava-farzan).

Comment: Relaxation is necessary for human because it enables him to recover the lost energy. So playing as an approach to get back to work is not denied. However playing too much is bad. These two are different; As nobody considers sleeping as wasting time.